# Is there a way to open multiple tabs at once with Selenium + Python?

Tags: python, selenium

When using:

```
browser.execute_script("window.open'Link', 'new window')")
```

I am only able to open one tab.  Is there a way to open multiple, like say 10 tabs of the same website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use send_keys with (Ctrl and T) to open new tab and then use get to enter the url you wish. Also you can track switch back and forth to all the tabs you have opened using window handles (driver.window_handles and driver.switch_to.window(handles)).